# Connection to MySQL for root User in Ubuntu fails

Tags: r, ubuntu, odbc

Hi I installed **ODBC** on **Ubuntu** to connect to a **MySQL** DB.

Running: `isql exasolution-uo2214lv1_64` works fine
but when I run it as sudo `sudo isql exasolution-uo2214lv1_64` 
I get the error:

> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

whats wrong here?

I want to use this connection in R via RODBC to download and process data from the DB. But In order to store results on the HDD I need to run R as sudo.

Please help.

Comment: Running `R` as root is very dangerous and shouldn't be done. Are you sure you *need* it? Can't you just create a folder with your user and store there the results?

Comment: hi nicola, of course I could do that. I am new to Ubuntu (Linux) and don't know exactly how to do that. Would you tell me? Why is it dangerous to run R as root?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved id myself. Thanks @nicola. I just used chmod for the directory and it works fine.